# Special characters displaying differently from p to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got an Angular web app and it appears that certain special characters are displaying in a div that I'm populating with the following:

```
dataHtml += "<span class='lead'>" + $sanitize(text) + ellipsis + "</span>";
```

On the frontend, that dataHtml is assigned to "source.data" it's being displayed as:

```
<p class="list-group-item-text">
        <cst-data value="source.data" class="{{ fsfield.sourceIndex === $index && 'text-muted'}}"></cst-data>
</p>
```

Now I've got a textarea that looks like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control input-lg"
                id="{{ fsfield.field }}"
                name="{{ fsfield.isTextArea ? fsfield.field : fsfield.field  + '-not_used'}}"
                placeholder="{{ fsfield.label }}"
                ng-focus="fsfield.editing = true"
                ng-blur="main.updateProps(fsfield)"
                ng-model="fsfield.value"
                ng-change="fsfield.userEdited = true"
                ng-pattern="fsfield.pattern"
                ng-required="fsfield.isRequired"
                rows="6" cols="100" select-on-click></textarea>
```

The end result is that the paragraph displays something like:

```
This was filmed at Kennedy's funeral.
```

But in the textarea, it looks like:

```
This was filmed at Kennedy&#x2019;s funeral.
```

After looking at the value in the database, it looks like the actual text value has '$#x2019;' that's being replaced by an apostrophe in the display. How do I get the text in the paragraph to look exactly like the text in the textarea?

Comment: You should be using the `$sce`statement to tell angular that it is safe and should be rendered as html. Can you try rewriting your cst-data tag as `<cst-data value="$sce(source.data)" class="{{ fsfield.sourceIndex === $index && 'text-muted'}}"></cst-data>`

Comment: Did you try $sce.trustAsHtml that value before binding?

Comment: I just got a bunch of errors. "Cannot read property of '0' of undefined.

Comment: have you try the directive ng-bind-html in your textarea tag ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml